# symlinking to `.rbenv/`: how much is too much?

Tags: symlink, version-control

I've been keeping most of my dotfiles in a git repo and symlinking to them, e.g.

```
ln -s ~/Development/dotfiles/bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
```

which has been great. I did something similar with `.vim/` and my `.vimrc`:

```
ln -s ~/Development/vim ~/.vim
ln -s ~/Development/vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

I just switched from RVM to rbenv, and I'm considering moving `.rbenv/` into a similar location and symlinking to it, i.e.

```
ln -s ~/Development/rbenv ~/.rbenv
```

rbenv itself makes heavy use of symlinks, plus I installed it via Homebrew, so I'm wondering if it's unwise to introduce another layer of indirection. Might it have a noticeable effect on performance? Am I taking things too far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless programs spend almost all their time to accede these files, this shouldn't be a problem. But I suggest that you test (possibly with a larger number of symlink indirections) and see if you can notice a loss of performance.

FYI, Debian introduces at least 2 level of symlink indirections for common programs via `/etc/alternatives`, and I don't think anyone complained.